# Is there a Window's Command Line Option to Show the Sizes of Directories

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, dir, directory-listing

When I do a `dir` command it, gives this information:

```
02/11/2015  01:39 PM    <DIR>          bar
11/11/2014  07:22 AM    <DIR>          buz
02/12/2015  01:35 PM       140,660,736 foo.sdf
01/21/2015  02:04 PM            10,505 foo.sln
01/21/2015  02:04 PM               256 foo.vssscc
```

Is there a switch or even a PowerShell command that I can do which will list all directories *with* their respective sizes?

Comment: See [so] question [How to list all folder with size via batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21711180)

Comment: not really a direct answer but cygwin http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VAD7x7Lr   list directories `find -type d`   list directories with sizes `du -h`

Comment: @barlop sadly no access to Cygwin. It has to be PowerShell it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trivial in PowerShell.

```
$FolderSize = Get-ChildItem $FolderPath -Recurse -Force | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum;

$FolderSize.Sum;       #Size in bytes
$FolderSize.Sum / 1MB; #Size in MB
$FolderSize.Sum / 1GB; #Size in GB
```

---

To get each folder in a specified folder and calculate each, just iterate through them:

```
$BaseFolder = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Path\To\Folder';

$Results = @();

foreach ($f in $BaseFolder) {
    if ($f.PSIsContainer -eq $true) {
        $Size = Get-ChildItem $f -Recurse -Force | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum;
    }
    else {
        $Size = Get-ChildItem $f | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum;
    }
    $Results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name = $f.Name; Length = $Size.Sum;}
}

$Results | Format-Table -AutoSize;
```

Comment: This gives me the total size of the current directory. It will not "list all directories with their respective sizes" as the question asks.

Comment: @JonathanMee See update.

Comment: That is perfect, and wonderful. Can you add a comment in the answer that `$BaseFolder = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Path\To\Folder';` needs to be set with the path to the folder you want to do the "dir" in? I just tried the code as-is and that obviously didn't work. I just want the next person through to be able to plug and play your code.